# How can I add warning feature to the GCC?

Tags: c, gcc

Example of usage:

```
void closefrom (int lowfd);

int main()
{
    // expected warning
    closefrom(-1);
    return 0;
}
```

Specifically: I should implement diagnostics (compiler warning) for function calls. Function located in glibc:
`void closefrom (int lowfd);`

If `lowfd` is negative compiler should issue a warning.

Here is some information about `closefrom`:

https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-alpha/2021-August/129718.html

Maybe **attribute** of the function will somehow help in this?

Comment: "How can I" is a bit too broad question. What compiler you will be using? `Maybe attribute` attribute is specific to a gcc compiler.

Comment: You are not expecting a solution that will work with *variables* passed to `foo`, are you?

Comment: In this case, maybe consider an `unsigned` instead?

Comment: @KamilCuk, I use gcc

Comment: @Neil, I can't realize this function. Specifically: I should implement diagnostics (compiler warning) for function calls. Function located in glibc:
```void closefrom (int lowfd);```

Comment: @EugeneSh., yes, I want to issue warning only if compiler is able to calculate the value (by optimizations, or if the value is constant). Otherwise just use function without warnings.

Comment: @levsha Then, if you are going to utilize the method Eric gave in the answer, you will get compile errors when passing any variables to it.

Comment: @EugeneSh., Eric's method is quite interesting, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Edit the question to clarify. “it doesn’t work for me” is not a vaild problem description. Show the desired behavior. In the question, you state “… I should issue a warning”. What do you mean “I”? You are a person. To issue a warning, write it down on a piece of paper and mail it to your friends. Or to your enemies. Or do you mean you want something in your build process to issue a warning when you build the project? Or do you mean you are writing or modifying a compiler and want to add this warning feature to the compiler?…

Comment: … Or you are writing a library interface and you want to do something to ensure the compiler issues a warning when your routine is called with a negative argument? If so, explain why the methods I provided are insufficient. Also, a web search for `closefrom` with glibc does not show anything illuminating. Is `closefrom` a glibc routine? Where is the documentation for it?

Comment: I think determining the value of the variable at compile-time, in general, is probably undecidable. Have you considered a standard `assert`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I am sorry for inaccurate description of the problem, I just wanted to get only a hint to make task, and not the solution of the problem, so it seemed to me that such a description of the problem is enough. I edited question, hope that the description of the problem is clear now.
Here is some information about ```closefrom```:
https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-alpha/2021-August/129718.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> want to issue warning only if compiler is able to calculate the value (by optimizations, or if the value is constant). Otherwise just use function without warnin

In short, with GNU extensions:

```
void foo (int lowfd);

#if defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__OPTIMIZE__)
#define curb(expr, msg) \
     __extension__({ \
          if (__builtin_constant_p(expr)) { \
              if (!(expr)) { \
                    __attribute__((__noinline__, \
                    __warning__(msg))) void warnit() {__asm__("");}; warnit(); \
              } \
           } \
     })
#else
#define curb(expr, msg)  (void)0
#endif

#define foo(x)  (curb(x >= 0, "x is lower than 0"), foo(x))

int main()
{
    // expected warning
    foo(-1);
    return 0;
}
```

I have this https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kamillibc/-/blob/master/libs/curb/src/curb.h#L46 in my tree about the idea of issuing a warning or error if the expression is known at compile time, and if it isn't, failing at runtime or not. The `&& defined(__OPTIMIZE__)` seems not to be needed in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it works and I even figured out exactly how. Only I don't understand why there is an assembler insert in the function ```warnit``` and why it is __noinline__. By the way, an error occurs during compilation related to the definition of a function ```warnit``` inside __extension__, so I just took it out from there, because I don't need a variable ```msg```, so the task is done.

Comment: `assembler insert in the function warnit and` So it isn't optimized out,, `__asm__` effectively prohibits optimization. `why it is noinline` Same reason. Optimizing the function out removes the potential warning. `an error` what error?

Comment: I am sorry, I was wrong, there is no compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this, but don’t:

```
void foo(int x) {}

#define foo(x)  foo(((int [(x)+1]){0}, (x)))

int main(void)
{
    foo(-1);
    return 0;
}
```

The macro attempts to create a compound literal consisting of an array with `(x)+1` elements. If `x` is negative, `(x)+1` will be negative or zero, and the compiler will complain about an improper size for the array. (This may require using compiler switches to disable a zero-length array extension.) If `x` is zero or positive, the compound literal will be discarded by the comma operator, and `foo` will be called with argument `x`. (When a macro name is used in its own replacement, it is not replaced again, so the function `foo` will be called.)

Note that overflow in `(x)+1` is possible. You could add a check against `INT_MAX` to deal with that.

This requires that `x` be some compile-time expression, which is implied in your question about how to check at compile time.

With Clang or GCC, you can combine a standard `_Static_assert` with a non-standard statement expression:

```
#define foo(x)  ({ _Static_assert((x) >= 0, "Argument to foo must be nonnegative."); foo(x); })
```

If `foo` is always `void`, you can simply use a `_Static_assert` with the `do … while` idiom to give it statement form when a semicolon is appended:

```
#define foo(x)  do { _Static_assert((x) >= 0, "Argument to foo must be nonnegative."); foo(x); } while (0)
```

If `x` can be something other than an `int`, such as a floating-point type, you might want to work on the conditions a bit to deal with issues that arise in the tests and conversions.

Comment: Thank you for answer, your method is quite interesting, but it doesn't work for me. I edited question to specify the problem.